# How do I filter the records of one array by those that do not exist in another array?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two result sets:

```
$array1 = (0=>'name1',1=>'name2');
```

and

```
$array2 = (0=>'name',1=>'name1',2=>'name2',3=>'name4');
```

I want to loop through array2 and eliminate any record that does exist in array1

For some reason I can't use this syntax:

```
select * where not in(select ....)
```

Comment: If you are having problems with your `select ... not in...`, post your code and perhaps we could help solving that problem.

Comment: problem is that the primary key is multi-fields key

Comment: If you are using Laravel and you need a SQL query to do that, you are not using Eloquent correctly... could you explain more what are you using and trying to do (models) ?

Comment: I'm using laravel with oracle db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a SQL `select` which has multiple fields for the key, you can use the following syntax...

```
SELECT *
FROM CompletedTasks
WHERE (userID, taskID) NOT IN
      ( SELECT userID, taskID
        FROM PlannedTasks
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve that.

You can merge both arrays in one and then use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to filter the duplicate values.

Other method is to use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to only return the unique values that are on array2 and not array1.

I would use `array_diff` like this

This is what I got

```php
$array1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'surname2', 'surname3'];

$array2 = ['name', 'name1', 'name2', 'name4', 'surname', 'surname3', 'surname2'];

var_dump(array_diff($array2, $array1));

array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [3]=> string(5) "name4" [4]=> string(7) "surname" }
```

Comment: i couldn't do that coz the problem is laravel query result array looks different